# Is slug is working in next export command in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, slug

I know The next export command generates a static HTML version of your Next.js application. But when i use slug in my project and build my app check in live the page is blank.

i want knowledge about slug and if it is working in next export command ?

Comment: This page might help: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export.